# Does a "babel" field in package.json take precedence over a .babelrc file?

Tags: babeljs

If I've got a `.babelrc` file **and** a `"babel"` field in `package.json`, what happens?

Do the settings get merged? And which settings take precedence?

The [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) don't say.

Answer (score 11):

Babel will take setting in .babelrc as final over cli or any other source of config.

No merging of settings will occur either as babel will drop any previous settings when it encounters .babelrc

So when .babelrc is present only the settings contained in that file will be active.

> Could you clarify your answer: Does this mean settings are merged and
>   those in .babelrc take precedence?

No settings will be merged and the .babelrc settings will take precedence over everything else.

The exception to this however could occur when webpack is used since having babel as a loader with option `babelrc: false,` will omit .babelrc setting from the webpack flow. This can be useful if there are other packages that rely on babel but are not necessery or compatible with webpack.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10734910)

Comment: Could you clarify your answer: Does this mean settings are merged and those in .babelrc take precedence?

Comment: @RonakShah This is a perfectly valid answer (though some clarification would be great).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!